# Converting JSON to model object fails while using @JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, modelattribute

The conversion of JSON to a model object fails when @JsonProperty annotation is used as follows:

Controller class snippet:

```
    @RequestMapping( value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doControl(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request ){
          return user.getId();
    }
```

Model class snippet:

```
    public User{
       @JsonProperty("user_id")
       private id;

       @JsonProperty("user_name")
       private name;

       //getters and setters
    }
```

When I pass an a json `{"user_id":1, "user_name":"foo" }` with the `POST` request `User` fields are `null`. Will Jsonproperty annotation work while using ModelAttribute annotation?

Answer (score 1):

It will work with `@RequestBody`. With `@RequestBody` you specify to Spring MVC that the annotated object is inside HTTP request's body. Spring MVC will then try to decode the object using appropriate HTTPMessageConverter - you want it to use message converter for json, so your POST request should include correct Content-Type header (e.g. `Content-Type: application/json`).

If you don't specify `@RequestBody` Spring MVC will try to populate the object using request parameters (e.g. as if you submitted regular HTTP POST form).

Hence:

`public String doControl(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request ){...}`